# Betting system which surely makes a profit in a fair game

Tags: probability, martingales

[image]

Any help for the following problem would be much appreciated, thanks!

For context, example 5.1.30 in the problem can be found here: https://web.stanford.edu/~montanar/TEACHING/Stat310B/amir_notes.pdf

Comment: A game in which any player can ensure a profit in a finite amount of time, is not a fair game.

Comment: @Peter While the math in this is beyond me, I suspect it's a generalization of the St. Petersburg paradox.

Comment: The title should say "almost surely" instead of "surely", I think.  The exercise only asserts that the probability is $1$.  The sequence of signs could be identically $-1$ after all.

Comment: Actually, when $k=1$, this *is* the St. Petersburg paradox.

Comment: Here's an updated version of your notes: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure what it means by "prior to your $k$-$s$ turn." What is $s$?